# Automatic Deployment of Java application on Remote Tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, deployment

I want to be able to automatically deploy a Java application to a tomcat server.

Current situation:

- A Java project is under developement in Eclipse
- A Tomcat Server is running on another machine, serving a WAR file of that project

My goal: **An easy possibility to compile and deploy the project into the remote Tomcat server.** I don't mind if that would be a console command/script or by using the Eclipse GUI.

Is that possible? If yes, how? (If there are possibilites, which need changes on my setup, feel free to give me advice for a better suiting setup)

### Update

Yes, i use Maven.

Comment: See: [Eclipse on-click deploy to remote Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254839/eclipse-on-click-deploy-to-remote-tomcat)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Maven I will suggest to use [Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) which supports all Tomcat's version and have ability to [deploy to local and remote servers](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container).

Comment: Sounds like what i need! Do you know if there is an Eclipse plugin supporting it? Maybe m2eclipse can handle it too?

Answer (score 7):

If you prefer not to go with Maven or the Cargo plugin you can simply invoke the [Tomcat manager deploy URL](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html). Under the covers Cargo is basically doing the same thing. Tomcat also provides [Ant tasks](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant) to wrap the manager commands. Using the Ant tasks would enable you to invoke them in Eclipse without a plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Cargo can do what you want in a general fashion (but I have not tried personally) http://cargo.codehaus.org/Tomcat+6.x

Also Tomcat has an administrative webapp that can accept WAR's by upload, but I would look at Cargo first.