# Eclipse and remote Tomcat 8 server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

After some time of research I didn't find a complete answer to this. My scenario is as follow:

1 Windows client with Eclipse.
1 Debian server with Tomcat 8.

The idea is to use the remote Tomcat server in the Windows machine to avoiding install the local Tomcat plugin on it, and deploy the projects directly to the remote server vía Eclipse. Is this possible?

As the information I've read, I'm afraid that the local Tomcat server is mandatory in order to get access to de Java Servlets API (package javax.servlet.*). I have a project in Eclipse without any Tomcat (remote nor local) and this package is not available so can't compile.

So, there is a way to achieve what I want? I'm a bit lost in this, so may I have some misleading concepts and simply this is not possible for some good reason :).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you read [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)?

Comment: Alberto it is not possible to do what you want, you need some dependecies of the webcontainer in your project

Comment: Thank you for the comments. Fge, I've just read that, thanks, I'll look for that deeply. @fmodos So, say that I have the local server. Is **then** some way to deploy the app to the remote server?

Comment: @Alberto the deploy is basically to copy the .war to the remote server, unless you use for ie: maven deployment

Comment: @fmodos Yes, I know, but when I run the project inside Eclipse, the IDE is deploying the app into the local server, right? I wish to know if it is possible to deploy the app in the remote server as well by clicking "Run" button or by some kind of SSH access inside Eclipse. If not, well, I'll have to do it manually. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've read over the Internet that using Maven Tomcat this can be accomplished.

Comment: See: [Eclipse on-click deploy to remote Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254839/eclipse-on-click-deploy-to-remote-tomcat)