# How to deploy a Java EE Webapp to a remote server directly from Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, webserver, vps

I have currently developed a web app and want to deploy it directly to my vps. Currently my deployment strategy constitutes of the following steps:

1. Export a WAR file from eclipse.
2. Upload the WAR file using ssh to my webapps directory.

I am looking for a better method to deploy apps to the server directly from eclipse.

Comment: You may find the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760297/remote-deploy-tomcat-webapp-from-eclipse  [OR]   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484055/automatic-deployment-of-java-application-on-remote-tomcat   [OR]    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823432/can-i-hot-deploy-to-a-remote-install-of-tomcat    [OR]     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254839/eclipse-on-click-deploy-to-remote-tomcat

Comment: See: [Eclipse on-click deploy to remote Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254839/eclipse-on-click-deploy-to-remote-tomcat)